# Count the number of "holes" in a bitmap

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, maze

Consider a MxN bitmap where the cells are 0 or 1.  '1' means filled and '0' means empty.

Find the number of 'holes' in the bitmap, where a hole is a contiguous region of empty cells.

For example, this has two holes:

```
11111  
10101  
10101  
11111
```

... and this has only one:

```
11111  
10001  
10101  
11111
```

What is the fastest way, when M and N are both between 1 and 8?

*Clarification*: diagonals are not considered contiguous, only side-adjacency matters.

*Note*: I am looking for something that takes advantage of the data format.  I know how to transform this into a graph and [BD]FS it but that seems overkill.

Comment: Why does this smell of either homework or code-golf? @Florin, thanks for the update. Please consider this remark "rescinded". We'll take your word.

Comment: it TASTES like homework!

Comment: It is not homework, but it doesn't matter.  I'm trying to solve a bigger problem and this is just a subproblem.

Comment: Are the holes only orthogonal connected?  Or is diagnonal also allowed?

Comment: I agree you need graph theory on this one.

Comment: The fastest way depends strongly how the bitmaps are stored before the algorithm.  NxM Matrix or bitfields or?

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger ~ Since he calls it a bitfield I think we can assume a bitmap. Additionally, we can easily convert this ahead of time into an NxM matrix before processing, so I think it's safe to assume we have a rectangular matrix with easily defined `(i-1,j-1)...(i+1,j+1)` neighbors for calculations sake.

Comment: Don't forget that bitmaps are stored upside down

Comment: @Sam Dufel - upside-down does not matter - the number of holes is the same.

Comment: The Euler number or Euler characteristic will give you the number of holes. And it can be computed just by examining each 2x2 neighborhood once. Here’s a nice write up: https://sydney4.medium.com/the-euler-number-of-a-binary-image-1d3cc9e57caa

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to do [connected component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Component_Labeling) on your image. You can use the [Two-pass algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Component_Labeling#Two-pass) described in the Wikipedia article I linked above. Given the small size of your problem, the [One-pass algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#One-pass_version) may suffice.

You could also use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)/[DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) but I'd recommend the above algorithms.

Comment: Yes, connected component labeling should do the trick. Also, congrats to 10k, @Jacob (or almost - I guess you hit rep-cap for today).

Comment: @Jonas: I know! Hopefully florin will accept this answer today :)

Comment: @Jonas: I can acknowledge the congrats now :D

Comment: I slightly changed Two-pass algorithm but the main idea is there
https://gist.github.com/atonamy/3c50f63aebdecc9b881756e889fb5278
give your comments if solution looks acceptable for coding interview

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a nice use of the disjoint-set data structure.
Convert the bitmap to a 2d array
loop through each element
if the current element is a 0, merge it with the set of one its 'previous' empty neighbors    (already visited)
if it has no empty neighbors, add it to its own set

then just count the number of sets

Comment: I wrote this answer before looking at his.

Answer (score 0):

There may be advantages gained by using table lookups and bitwise operations.

For example whole line of 8 pixels may be looked up in 256 element table, so number of holes in a field 1xN is got by single lookup. Then there may be some lookup table of 256xK elements, where K is number of hole configurations in previous line, contatining number of complete holes and next hole configuration. That's just an idea.

Comment: I just started building my 2^64 lookup table, but I ran out of the budget for the year for RAM 8^)

Comment: florin: Use distributed computing! =)

Comment: I found this puzzle very interesting and I spent some free time to make  a sketch of 'line by line' algorithm with lookups and bitwise operations, using only 560 bytes of tables (for 8 bit wide patterns). Here's the code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13343791/holecount2.c Sorry if code not well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article describe the answer on Medium https://medium.com/@ahmed.wael888/bitmap-holes-count-using-typescript-javascript-387b51dd754a

but here is the code, the logic isn't complicated and you can understand it without reading the article.

```
export class CountBitMapHoles {
    bitMapArr: number[][];
    holesArr: Hole[] = [];
    maxRows: number;
    maxCols: number;

    constructor(bitMapArr: string[] | number[][]) {
        if (typeof bitMapArr[0] == 'string') {
            this.bitMapArr = (bitMapArr as string[]).map(
                (word: string): number[] => word.split('').map((bit: string): number => +bit))
        } else {
            this.bitMapArr = bitMapArr as number[][]
        }
        this.maxRows = this.bitMapArr.length;
        this.maxCols = this.bitMapArr[0].length;
    }

    moveToDirection(direction: Direction, currentPosition: number[]) {
        switch (direction) {
            case Direction.up:
                return [currentPosition[0] - 1, currentPosition[1]]

            case Direction.down:
                return [currentPosition[0] + 1, currentPosition[1]]

            case Direction.right:
                return [currentPosition[0], currentPosition[1] + 1]

            case Direction.left:
                return [currentPosition[0], currentPosition[1] - 1]

        }
    }
    reverseDirection(direction: Direction) {
        switch (direction) {
            case Direction.up:
                return Direction.down;
            case Direction.down:
                return Direction.up
            case Direction.right:
                return Direction.left
            case Direction.left:
                return Direction.right
        }
    }
    findNeighbor(parentDir: Direction, currentPosition: number[]) {
        let directions: Direction[] = []
        if (parentDir === Direction.root) {
            directions = this.returnAvailableDirections(currentPosition);
        } else {
            this.holesArr[this.holesArr.length - 1].positions.push(currentPosition)
            directions = this.returnAvailableDirections(currentPosition).filter((direction) => direction != parentDir);
        }
        directions.forEach((direction) => {
            const childPosition = this.moveToDirection(direction, currentPosition)
            if (this.bitMapArr[childPosition[0]][childPosition[1]] === 0 && !this.checkIfCurrentPositionExist(childPosition)) {
                this.findNeighbor(this.reverseDirection(direction), childPosition)
            }
        });
        return
    }
    returnAvailableDirections(currentPosition: number[]): Direction[] {
        if (currentPosition[0] == 0 && currentPosition[1] == 0) {
            return [Direction.right, Direction.down]
        } else if (currentPosition[0] == 0 && currentPosition[1] == this.maxCols - 1) {
            return [Direction.down, Direction.left]
        } else if (currentPosition[0] == this.maxRows - 1 && currentPosition[1] == this.maxCols - 1) {
            return [Direction.left, Direction.up]
        } else if (currentPosition[0] == this.maxRows - 1 && currentPosition[1] == 0) {
            return [Direction.up, Direction.right]
        } else if (currentPosition[1] == this.maxCols - 1) {
            return [Direction.down, Direction.left, Direction.up]
        } else if (currentPosition[0] == this.maxRows - 1) {
            return [Direction.left, Direction.up, Direction.right]
        } else if (currentPosition[1] == 0) {
            return [Direction.up, Direction.right, Direction.down]
        } else if (currentPosition[0] == 0) {
            return [Direction.right, Direction.down, Direction.left]
        } else {
            return [Direction.right, Direction.down, Direction.left, Direction.up]
        }
    }
    checkIfCurrentPositionExist(currentPosition: number[]): boolean {
        let found = false;
        return this.holesArr.some((hole) => {
            const foundPosition = hole.positions.find(
                (position) => (position[0] == currentPosition[0] && position[1] == currentPosition[1]));
            if (foundPosition) {
                found = true;
            }
            return found;
        })

    }

    exec() {
        this.bitMapArr.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
            row.forEach((bit, colIndex) => {
                if (bit === 0) {
                    const currentPosition = [rowIndex, colIndex];
                    if (!this.checkIfCurrentPositionExist(currentPosition)) {
                        this.holesArr.push({
                            holeNumber: this.holesArr.length + 1,
                            positions: [currentPosition]
                        });
                        this.findNeighbor(Direction.root, currentPosition);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(this.holesArr.length)
        this.holesArr.forEach(hole => {
            console.log(hole.positions)
        });
        return this.holesArr.length
    }
}
enum Direction {
    up = 'up',
    down = 'down',
    right = 'right',
    left = 'left',
    root = 'root'
}

interface Hole {
    holeNumber: number;
    positions: number[][]
}
```

main.ts file

```
import {CountBitMapHoles} from './bitmap-holes'

const line = ['1010111', '1001011', '0001101', '1111001', '0101011']
function main() {
    const countBitMapHoles = new CountBitMapHoles(line)
    countBitMapHoles.exec()
}

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function BitmapHoles(strArr) { 
    let returnArry = [];
    let indexOfZ = [];
    let subarr;
     for(let i=0 ; i < strArr.length; i++){
       subarr = strArr[i].split("");
      let index = [];
      for(let y=0 ; y < subarr.length; y++){
        if(subarr[y] == 0)
        index.push(y);
        if(y == subarr.length-1)
        indexOfZ.push(index);
      }
    }
    for(let i=0 ; i < indexOfZ.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<indexOfZ[i].length ; j++){
          if(indexOfZ[i+1] && (indexOfZ[i][j]==indexOfZ[i+1][j] || indexOfZ[i+1].indexOf(indexOfZ[i][j])))
          returnArry.indexOf(strArr[i]) < 0 ? returnArry.push(strArr[i]): false;
          if(Math.abs(indexOfZ[i][j]-indexOfZ[i][j+1])==1)
          returnArry.indexOf(strArr[i]) < 0 ? returnArry.push(strArr[i]): false;
        }
    }
    
      return returnArry.length; 
    
    }
       
    // keep this function call here 
    console.log(BitmapHoles(readline()));
```

Comment: This answer might be more useful if you explain how the code works and how it relates to the question.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function findHoles(map) {
    let hole = 0;

    const isHole = (i, j) => map[i] && map[i][j] === 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (isHole(i, j)) {
                markHole(i, j);
                hole++;
            }
        }
    }

    function markHole(i, j) {
        if (isHole(i, j)) {
            map[i][j] = 2;
            markHole(i, j - 1);
            markHole(i, j + 1);
            markHole(i + 1, j);
            markHole(i - 1, j);
        }
    }

    return hole;
}
```

Comment: This answer might be more useful if you explain how the code works and how it relates to the question.